# Artifactory missing 'advanced' menu

Tags: artifactory

I have setup an artifactory server, and made myself an administrator. 
Today I logged in to find that I am no longer able to access the 'advanced' menu.

I've ensured that my user account is still and administrator. I've logged out and back in. When I login as the 'admin' account that I first setup with artifactory, I see that the 'advanced' menu *is* available.

My user account
[image]

Admin user account
[image]

Why has my user account suddenly lost access to the advanced menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-17574) when you have your browser zoomed in more than 150%

Zoom out on your browser. Usually with `ctrl` `-`

Comment: This just hit me today w/ AF 6.23.41 and Chrome set to 100%.  I had to go up to 125% to see that admin menu section!

Comment: Yeah, I was at zoom of 110% and hit this as well.  Reset to 100% allowed the UI to draw correctly.